# R: process data frame subgroups and merge results together

Tags: r

I need to process three data frames containing the same subgroups (name). So far I've been using this approach:

```
results = data.frame(name = factor("dummy"), col1 = 1, col = 2) 
for( name in df1$name ) {
  new.results = process(name, df1[df1$name == name, ], df2[df2$name == name,], df3[df3$name == name, ]
  results = rbind(results, new.results)
}

return(results)
```

The problem with this code is that the process() function must return the same layout than the 'results' data frame. If I change the contents returned by process() I also have to change the outer function. Also the first row in the results data frame must be removed.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: where does function `process()` come from and what is it doing?

Comment: What I am asking is how to stitch data frames together without knowing the data frame format in 'new.results'. process() always returns the same data frame format. Is there a way to avoid the very first line in the code?

Comment: Sorry - maybe I'm a being a bit dense, but can you explain further what stitching data frames together means? Is it safe to assume that `process()` is some internal function you've written up yourself? If so, do you need to apply `process()` by each level in the column `name`? Or is there more to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [plyr](http://plyr.had.co.nz/) package. For example:

```
data_out = ddply(
    .data = data_in
    , .variables = .(name)
    , .fun = process
)
```

Comment: The title of this question almost read like the short description of plyr :)